# Keeping static objects visible in 3D Plotly Graph using updating steps (updating objects) with slider

Tags: python, plotly

I have created a 3D plot using Plotly in Python to visualize the orbits of Earth and Mars around the Sun. The plot displays the orbits of Earth and Mars as lines, and their positions as markers. There is also a slider to animate the positions of Earth and Mars over time.

The problem I'm facing is that when I initially load the plot, I can see the orbits of Earth and Mars, and everything looks fine. However, as soon as I touch the slider to animate the positions, the orbits of Earth and Mars disappear. I want to keep both the orbits and the positions of Earth and Mars visible when using the slider.

Here is my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from astropy.time import Time
from astropy.coordinates import get_body_barycentric

def plot_earth_and_mars_orbit(start_date, end_date):
    # Convert start and end dates to Julian Dates
    jd_start = start_date.jd
    jd_end = end_date.jd

    # Define the range of dates
    jd_range = np.linspace(jd_start, jd_end, 365)
    dates = Time(jd_range, format='jd')

    # Get the position of Earth and Mars relative to the Solar System barycenter
    earth_positions = [get_body_barycentric('earth', date).xyz.to_value('au') for date in dates]
    mars_positions = [get_body_barycentric('mars', date).xyz.to_value('au') for date in dates]
    
    # Extract X, Y, and Z components for Earth and Mars
    x_earth, y_earth, z_earth = np.array(earth_positions).T
    x_mars, y_mars, z_mars = np.array(mars_positions).T

    # Create a 3D plot
    fig = go.Figure()

    # Add Earth's and Mars' orbit as lines
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x_earth, y=y_earth, z=z_earth, mode='lines', name='Earth Orbit'))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x_mars, y=y_mars, z=z_mars, mode='lines', name='Mars Orbit'))

    # Add initial position of Earth and Mars as markers
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[x_earth[0]], y=[y_earth[0]], z=[z_earth[0]], mode='markers', marker=dict(size=5, color='blue'), name='Earth'))
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[x_mars[0]], y=[y_mars[0]], z=[z_mars[0]], mode='markers', marker=dict(size=5, color='red'), name='Mars'))

    # Add the Sun at the origin (Solar System barycenter)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=[0], y=[0], z=[0], mode='markers', marker=dict(size=10, color='yellow'), name='Sun'))

    # Define steps for the slider
    steps = []
    for i, date in enumerate(dates):
        step = dict(
            method="update",
            args=[{
                # Update only the positions of Earth and Mars
                "x": [[], [], [x_earth[i]], [x_mars[i]], [0]],  # Update Earth and Mars x positions
                "y": [[], [], [y_earth[i]], [y_mars[i]], [0]],  # Update Earth and Mars y positions
                "z": [[], [], [z_earth[i]], [z_mars[i]], [0]],  # Update Earth and Mars z positions
            }, {
                "title": f"Date: {date.iso}"  # Update the plot title to show the current date
            }],
            label=date.datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        )
        steps.append(step)
        
    # Create the sliders using the steps
    sliders = [dict(
        active=0,
        currentvalue={"prefix": "Date: "},
        pad={"t": 50},
        steps=steps
    )]
    
    # Update the layout of the plot
    fig.update_layout(
        title='Earth and Mars Orbit around the Sun',
        sliders=sliders,
        scene=dict(
            xaxis_title='X (AU)', yaxis_title='Y (AU)', zaxis_title='Z (AU)',
            xaxis=dict(range=[-2.5, 2.5]), yaxis=dict(range=[-2.5, 2.5]), zaxis=dict(range=[-2.5, 2.5]),
            aspectmode='cube'
        )
    )
    
    fig.show()
    
start_date = Time('2021-01-01')
end_date = Time('2024-12-31')
plot_earth_and_mars_orbit(start_date, end_date)
```

After some testing, I discovered a solution to keep the orbits visible: by updating the full orbits of Earth and Mars at each slider step, even though their paths do not change. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
# Define steps for the slider
    steps = []
    for i, date in enumerate(dates):
        step = dict(
            method="update",
            args=[{
                # Update all objects:
                "x": [x_earth, x_mars, [x_earth[i]], [x_mars[i]], [0]],  # Update Earth and Mars x positions
                "y": [y_earth, y_mars, [y_earth[i]], [y_mars[i]], [0]],  # Update Earth and Mars y positions
                "z": [z_earth, z_mars, [z_earth[i]], [z_mars[i]], [0]],  # Update Earth and Mars z positions
            },
```

While this approach works, it significantly increases the file size – from 3.7MB for the static orbit plus updated planet position version to 19.5MB when updating the orbits at each step (all objects are updated). Since I plan to add many static objects, is there a way to keep the orbits of Earth and Mars static and visible when using the slider? Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.